# How to forward records to multiple Kafka Stream child Processors at once?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, stream-processing

In Kafka Stream API, is it possible to forward more than one record at once to different child processors ? For an example, let say we have a parent processor called Processor-Parent and two child processors, Child-1, Child-2.

When Processor-Parent receives a record to process, I would like to do the following.

```
new_record = create_new_record(current_record)
context.forward(new_record, To(Child-1))
context.forward(old_record, To(Child-2))
```

Is this a good practice to forward records like this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your requirenments:

- If your logic is straight forward you can even use Kafka Streams DSL.
- If it is a *little* more complex and you need Procesor API, but you want pass same records to two Processors you can do it like @Sameer Killamsetty mentioned.

```java
builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    builder.addSource(SOURCE, kafkaTopic)
.addProcessor("child1", () -> new child1(), SOURCE)
.addProcessor("child2", () -> new child2(), SOURCE);
```

- If it is more complex and depends on some logic in Processor you want to pass message to different Processor node you can do that.

```java
builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    builder.addSource(SOURCE, kafkaTopic)
.addProcessor("InputProcessor", () -> new InputProcessor(), SOURCE)
.addProcessor("child1", () -> new child1(), "InputProcessor")
.addProcessor("child2", () -> new child2(), "InputProcessor");
```

```java
public class InputProcessor extends AbstractProcessor<String, String> {
    @Override
    public void process(String key, String value) {
        try {
            context().forward(key, Integer.parseInt(value), To.child("child1"));
            context().forward(key, value, To.child("child2"));
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            context().forward(key, value, To.child("child2"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: .addProcessor("child1", () -> new child1(), "InputProcessor")
.addProcessor("child2", () -> new child2(), "InputProcessor");  can we execute these two processors in parallel?

Answer (score -2):

This is not best practice. Instead, create your toplogy with one parent processor and multiple child processors.

```
builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    builder.addSource(SOURCE, kafkaTopic)
.addProcessor("child1", () -> new child1(),SOURCE)
.addProcessor("child2", () -> new child2(),SOURCE);
```

in this way,kafka streams ensure every message comes to the source goes to both the child processors.

Comment: Looks like you've got the question wrong. Whole idea is to handle messages differently using different processors. As an example you can image multi schema topic and consumer which should handle data different depending upon event type.